# Installing SQL Server 2012 Express using bootstrapper

Tags: sql-server

I am having an issue where I have both the x86 and x64 versions of SQL Server Express 2012 .
So if the OS is 64 bit install the 64 bit version, if the OS is 32 bit install the 32 bit version.Please help me.
Using Bootstrapped manifest generator .How to modify the product.xml or package.xml for installation condition

Comment: AFAIK, you will need to download both versions and write a bat file which checks OS version and install accordingly

Comment: How to write bat file for that.

Comment: Please give me bat file for that